# Reflection struct field.Set with a Flag pointer value

Tags: pointers, go, command-line-interface, reflect

I have a bunch of flags parsed, and I'm then trying to assign those values to fields in a struct, but I'm struggling to get a parsed flag value set into the struct because I can't type assert it or cast it.

Here is a snippet of the code I have. It's not important to worry too much about the `IterFields` function, basically the third argument is called for each field in the struct...

> Note: there are comments in the code below which highlight the error(s).

```golang
    flag.Parse()

    IterFields(st, v, func(field reflect.Value, sf reflect.StructField) {
        flag.VisitAll(func(f *flag.Flag) {
            if f.Name == strings.ToLower(sf.Name) || f.Name == sf.Tag.Get("short") {
                fmt.Printf("%+v, %T\n", f.Value, f.Value)
                // PRINTS: true, *flag.boolValue
                
                if v, ok := f.Value.(bool); ok {
                    fmt.Println("ok")
                } else {
                    fmt.Println("not ok")
                }
                // ERROR: impossible type assertion: bool does not implement flag.Value (missing Set method)
                
                field.Set(reflect.ValueOf(f.Value))
                // PANIC: value of type *flag.boolValue is not assignable to type bool
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.Value` is an interface type [`flag.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Value) abstracting all kinds of flag values. As your code indicates, it's not of type `bool` but some non-exported `*flag.boolValue`. You shouldn't be concerned about its dynamic type.

You may use the `Value.String()` method to get its value as a `string`, which will be either `"false"` or `"true"` for bool types, you may use simple comparison to obtain a `bool` from it like `f.Value.String() == "true"`.

But a better approach would be: all `flag.Value` values originating from the `flag` package also implement [`flag.Getter`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Getter) which also has a `Get()` method that will directly return a `bool` value in case of a bool flag (wrapped in `interface{}` of course). Just use that:

```
field.Set(reflect.ValueOf(f.Value.(flag.Getter).Get()))
```

The above works for fields of any type (given that the flag's value type is assignable to the field's type).

For `bool` fields only, alternatively you may also use:

```
field.SetBool(f.Value.(flag.Getter).Get().(bool))
```